# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have an SSL certificate on the production server of my website, but when I run the website site on the local server I see a security message because there is no certificate locally.

What can I add to the htaccess file to prevent HTTPS from being run on the Localhost?

My current htaccess code is below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: You can't bypass having a valid cert. If the request comes in to https it must have a valid cert or you'll get that warning. Rewrite rules are parsed after the ssl validation is made for a valid cert. So it will never work. That's by design.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're asking.

If you're asking how to prevent `http://localhost/some_path` from being rewritten by Apache mod_rewrite to `https://www.localhost/some_path`, then 
try adding this just before `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  Your solution worked.  Thanks